# Запуск сервиса prometheus-nginx-exporter на CentOS 7 [VMBitrix 7.5.2]

Tags: linux, nginx, centos, centos7, systemd

помогите решить проблему запуска сервиса для модуля экспортера prometheus-nginx-exporter

Установлен пакет prometheus-nginx-exporter через Snap

В конфигах NGINX я добавил

/etc/nginx/bx/site_settings/default/prometheus-nginx-exporte.conf

```
location /stub_status {
stub_status;
allow 127.0.0.1;
deny all;
}
```

/etc/nginx/bx/site_avaliable/s1.conf

```
# For prometheus-nginx-exporter
listen 8080 default_server;
```

Заглушка метрики отдается по 8080 порту, тут все ок, проверял через браузер и Сurl
**http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status**

Но проблема в следующем
.к prometheus-nginx-exporter не имеет демона, то нужно было создать Unit`ы я их создал https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter/tree/main/examples/systemd

**/etc/systemd/system/nginx_exporter.service**

```
Description=NGINX Prometheus Exporter
Requires=nginx_exporter.socket

[Service]
User=nginx_exporter
ExecStart=/var/lib/snapd/snap/nginx-prometheus-exporter/70/nginx-prometheus-exporter --nginx.scrape-uri="http://127.0.0.1:8080/stub_status"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

и

**/etc/systemd/system/nginx_exporter.socket**

```
Description=NGINX Prometheus Exporter

[Socket]
ListenStream=9113

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

Но не получается стартануть сервис, вылетает в ошибку, можете подсказать ее причины?

**$ systemctl daemon-reload**
**$ systemctl start nginx_exporter**
**$ systemctl status nginx_exporter**

Ошибки в системном журнале при попытке старта сервиса вылетают такие

```
сен 24 21:54:04 admin87.fvds.ru polkitd[481]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:18615:236960770 (system bus name :1.758613 [/usr/bin/pkttyagent --notify-fd 5 --fallback], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale ru_RU.UTF-8)
сен 24 21:54:04 admin87.fvds.ru systemd[1]: Started nginx_exporter.service.
сен 24 21:54:04 admin87.fvds.ru systemd[18621]: Failed at step USER spawning /var/lib/snapd/snap/nginx-prometheus-exporter/70/nginx-prometheus-exporter: No such process
сен 24 21:54:04 admin87.fvds.ru systemd[1]: nginx_exporter.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
сен 24 21:54:04 admin87.fvds.ru systemd[1]: Unit nginx_exporter.service entered failed state.
сен 24 21:54:04 admin87.fvds.ru systemd[1]: nginx_exporter.service failed.
сен 24 21:54:04 admin87.fvds.ru polkitd[481]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:18615:236960770 (system bus name :1.758613, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale ru_RU.UTF-8) (disconnected from bus)
```

Главное там, как мне кажется, вот что, но как это исправить не могу понять...

**Failed at step USER spawning /var/lib/snapd/snap/nginx-prometheus-exporter/70/nginx-prometheus-exporter: No such process**

пробовал менять на (по советам отсюда https://superuser.com/questions/1156676/what-causes-systemd-failed-at-step-user-spawning-usr-sbin-opendkim-no-such-p)

```
User=root
Group=root
```

или даже полностью убирать директивы User и Group

не помогло...

Comment: А почему у вас на centos откуда-то взялся snap?

Comment: Ну да ладно, в любом случае вопрос сводится к тому, как правильно запускать snap-приложения через systemd, и к nginx или prometheus он вообще не имеет отношения (а вы даже snap в метки не добавили)

Comment: (а, метки snap, оказывается, не существует... надо бы создать, наверное)